# Возвращается nil при вводе пробела в TextField

Tags: ios, swift

Есть апи поиска
Все работает хорошо до того момента пока я не введу пробел в `TextField`
Когда я это делаю то вылазит ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал делать это

```
?? " "
```

Все равно возвращается nil
Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Покажите Outlet текстфилда

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var search_text: UITextField!

Comment: Странно, с виду все нормально. Может Текстфилд какой-то кривой по свойствам?

Comment: Нет, все верно, Керим Хасбулатов скинул ответ, он подходит под эту ситуацию

Comment: Да я уже понял ) nil рождается не в текстфилде, а когда создается реквест.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В следующий раз не скидывай скриншот пожалуйста, а скидывай текст кода.

Оберни строку следующим образом

```
    let escapedString = search_text.rext!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)

let string = "http://gnext.kz........./?term=\(escapedString)"
```

Comment: Да это помогло, спасибо

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста! :)